# How to use Dapper.QueryMultiple with Sqlite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, dapper

The Dapper [documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) states you can send off multiple queries at once and iterate over the results using the QueryMultiple method like so:

```
var sql = @"
select * from foo where id = @paramname
select * from bar where id = @paramname";

conn.QueryMultiple(sql, new {paramname = paramval});
```

It would appear using sqlite like this doesn't work, throwing up invalid sql near "select". How do I use querymultiple with sqlite?

Comment: separate those queries with a `;` in between... never mind just saw your answer.

Comment: why the downvote? I noted it wasn't in the docs, and so wanted to share my knowledge with stackoverflow.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but that is a detail of [sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), not dapper.

Comment: Indeed, but I've never used Sqlite like this before, so was stumped by the problem, and took a bit of trial and error. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: @Habib seriously? Of course it can be reproduced. Typographical error? So clearly, in your opinion all coding problems are typographical errors because the characters just are not in the correct place. You just seem annoyed because you can't get votes for your answer. Stack overflow is a Q+A site. I had a question, it was answered.

Comment: @user3791372, It just a single close vote, If the community thinks otherwise this will remain open.  Having a semicolon between multiple statements in SQL is part of SQL Syntax. So yes I believe this is a typographical error.

Comment: @user3791372, what answer ? I never answered this question. It was just a comment pointing out the mistake and then I saw your self answer. I haven't downvoted your question and I don't even see a single downvote on either your question or answer, so not really sure why you think I will be annoyed. But I will just leave it here.

Comment: @Habib so all the documentation and usage examples for dapper with regards to querymultiple, including other questions with example code on stackoverflow contain a typo? You need to update the documentation of dapper then.

Comment: @user3791372 The need for the semicolon will vary with the DB being used, so I don't think that's up to dapper to document.  The idea is that a user of Dapper needs to know the correct syntax for the DB they are using.  My guess is their example are for SQL Server which is more widely used and more lax with the requirement for semicolons.

Comment: @juharr but as a newbie, I didn't know if dapper is doing something special / magical with the string to separate the queries (such as it does with the "id/Id" column name). Therefore, I consider it a valid question. As someone who doesn't use SQL Server, I wouldn't know how lax it was with the SQL!

Comment: @user3791372, seeing the [comment from Marc Gravell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721681/how-to-use-dapper-querymultiple-with-sqlite#comment45733478_28721682) I believe this is a specific issue with SQlite and Dapper, your question is absolutely valid, I have retracted my close vote, +1 for your answer and question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some playing, I noted that you appear to need to use a semicolon between the commands

so the above code corrected becomes:

```
var sql = @"
select * from foo where id = @paramname;
select * from bar where id = @paramname";

conn.QueryMultiple(sql, new {paramname = paramval});
```

No, don't use the code like this, use the return of a `QueryMultiple` as a `using` statement, so it can be automatically disposed of.

Comment: Handy to know (specifically: that sqlite requires `;` between commands) - ta; note that this also works in things like SQL Server, but is optional in most common scenarios